# java package com.google.common.collect.Range< LocalDate > intersection returns a wrong intersection

Tags: java, time, guava, intersection

I have this code:

```
private Range<LocalDate> datesRange;
```

and

```
intersection = !this.datesRange.isConnected(otherConditionBl.datesRange) ?
                    null :
                    this.datesRange.intersection(otherConditionBl.datesRange);
```

how come there is an intersection for this input?

```
this.datesRange = {Range@5802} "[2017-04-11..2017-04-12)"
otherConditionBl.datesRange = {Range@5801} "[2017-04-12..2017-04-14]"
this.datesRange.intersection(otherConditionBl.datesRange) = {Range@7036} "[2017-04-12..2017-04-12)"
```

Where can i report a bug for this?

Comment: Guava bugtracker is here: https://github.com/google/guava/issues

Comment: As a side note: if you're dealing with date ranges, you probably want to use something like [ThreeTen-Extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) or [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J), not Guava ranges which does not necessary fit time domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#intersection(com.google.common.collect.Range)).

> The resulting range may be empty; for example, [1..5) intersected with [5..7) yields the empty range [5..5)

If you look closely, the range returned is actually empty. It consists of all dates `x` such, that `2017-04-12` ≤ `x` < `2017-04-12`, which is impossible to satisfy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, that shows the reported behavior is not a bug. I have to say, though, that makes the business about connectedness and intersection logically inconsistent. I'm sure there's some other justification for it.

Comment: Not sure, why you'd think so. As it says in the documentation of `isConnected`: ["Returns true if there exists a (possibly empty) range which is enclosed by both this range and other."](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#isConnected(com.google.common.collect.Range)) In other words: `isConnected` is not the same as "overlaps"/"intersects" (in a mathematical sense), and this seems to be intentional.

Comment: Right, the business about returning an empty range is what makes it a little nutty. If it's sometimes OK to return an empty range, why does `intersection` require `isConnected`? Why not return an empty range in general instead of sometimes throwing an exception? Also, all empty ranges are equivalent. Why return [x, x) ? Why not [1, 1) or [100, 100) ? Why doesn't the symbolic `all` have a corresponding symbolic complement which would presumably be called `none` ?

Comment: @RobertDodler This particular example is for dates.  You said [1, 1) as an example empty range; what would that mean for dates?  Not all `Comparable` types have any sort of pickable default like that.  So `intersection` works when there's a range that's a subrange of both, in the sense of "the boundaries of the subrange are within the boundaries of the outer range."  So the guarantee is that lowerBound(intersection(a, b)) is >= lowerBound(a) and >= lowerBound(b), etc.